# Use of Virtual column in SELECT query Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to understand how we can use virtual variable created in select query. Like in below example I have created RequestDate and ReceivedDate  as part of select query which I would like to use in third select query in same scope.. Is it possible to do so ..? pls advise.

```
SELECT MessageId,
(  SELECT 
    xxxx from xxx where xxx
 ) AS RequestDate ,


( SELECT 
xxxx from xxx where xxx
) AS ReceivedDate ,

(
SELECT 
ReceivedDate - RequestDate from xxxx
) as DateDiff
FROM Date
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT MessageId,RequestDate ,ReceivedDate ,
       ReceivedDate - RequestDate as DateDiff
FROM (
       SELECT MessageId,
              (SELECT  xxxx from xxx where xxx) AS RequestDate ,
              (SELECT  xxxx from xxx where xxx) AS ReceivedDate ,
        FROM Date 
     ) As Z
```

**NOTE :** 
Your inner queries `(SELECT  xxxx from xxx where xxx)` and `(SELECT  xxxx from xxx where xxx)` should necessarily return single value for each row returned from DATE table otherwise you will get error

*Oracle update: **ORA-01427**: single-row subquery returns more than one row*

Comment: Hi Hasan, Thanks for response. Here in my case I have already created RequestDate  and ReceivedDate  column as part of other select block.  as part of my select block, now I want to use these variable in 3rd block

Comment: After calculating RecievedDate and RequestDate in subqueries you can do further calculation on them by accessing them from outer query . RecievedDate and RequestDate are alias name and are not available for further calculation as required in calculatinfg DateDiff in SAME select block , that is why you have to use subquery as shown above

Comment: Thanks, do we have any other option.. above option is not acceptable as we cant have that much select for accessing same block.. if we can have declare variable as global as assign these values to them and later we can use...

Comment: are the inner select queries returning only SINGLE value ?

Comment: Yes, they return single value.. I have a conditional block to display only one reord